# Sencha Touch - big XML file issue

Tags: performance, xml-parsing, sencha-touch

I am reading the content out from a xml file over the internet!

The file contains about 10000 xml-elements and is loaded into a list (one picture and headline for each element)!
This slows down the app extremly!

Is there a way to speed this up?
Maybe with a select-command?

Are there some examples or tutorials out there?

Answer (score 0):

You are out of luck for a easy-straight forward answer.

If you control the server that the XML file is coming from, you should make the changes on it to support pagination of the results instead of sending the complete document.

If you don't control the server, you could set up one to proxy the results and do the pagination for the application on the server side.

The last option is the process the file in chunks. This would mean, processing sub-strings of the text. Just take a sub-string of the first x characters, parse it and then do something with the results. If you needed more you would process the next x characters.  This could get very messy fast (as XML doesn't really parse nicely in this manner) and just downloading a document with 10k elements and loading it into memory is probably going to be taxing/slow/expensive (if downloading over a 3G connection) for mobile devices.